# Inheriting from immutable types

Tags: python, string, list, inheritance, int

I'd like to know how inheritance works for `int`, `list`, `string` and other immutable types.

Basically I'd just inherit a class like this:

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __init__(self, value):
        ?!?!?
```

I can't seem to figure out, how do I set the value like it's set for `int`? If I do `self.value = value` then my class will be used like this:

```
mi = MyInt(5)
print(mi.value) # prints 5
```

Whereas I want to use it like this:

```
mi = MyInt(5)
print(mi) # prints 5
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can subclass `int`, but because it is *immutable* you need to provide a [`.__new__()` constructor hook](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        new_myint = super(MyInt, cls).__new__(cls, value)
        return new_myint
```

You do need to call the base `__new__` constructor to get your subclass properly created.

In Python 3, you can omit the arguments to `super()` altogether:

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        new_myint = super().__new__(cls, value)
        return new_myint
```

Of course, this assumes you wanted to manipulate `value` before passing in to `super().__new__()` or manipulate `new_myint` some more before returning; otherwise you may as well remove the whole `__new__` method and just implement this as `class MyInt(int): pass`.

Comment: Alright, that's more complicated than I thought. But I do understand what it does tho. For python 3, can't I just use `super()` instead of `super(MyInt, cls)`? Also can I still create methods and/or other attributes for this?

Comment: That inner `__new__` call should be `__new__(cls, value)`.

Comment: @PatrikLippojoki Yes, just `super()` should work fine. And custom methods work just as you expect. Just note that the actual int value is accessible through just `self` within the methods.

Comment: @PatrikLippojoki: Yes, for Python 3 you can omit the arguments.

Comment: @poke: yeah, it's a static method, not a class method, as it turns out. :-P

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept asap ! :)

Comment: just curious, is there a reason to use cls over self?

Comment: Oh btw., I think this is worth noting, you *only* need to override the class constructor `__new__`, if you actually want to do something special on construction (like initializing other properties etc.). But if you don’t, you can just leave it out and it will work. So `class MyInt(int): pass` would be a perfect subtype.

Comment: @monkut As far as I understand, when you call `__new__` the object is not constructed yet, so there is no such thing as `self` (the object doesn't exist). `cls` means the class itself, so we're constructing a new instance of that class.

Comment: @monkut That is just a convention to make it clear that it is *not* an instance method. The value that is passed in is actually the type, i.e. a reference to `MyInt`, while `self` would represent an actual object of said type. The object is only being created during the `__new__`.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to implement `__new__` in this case. Actually, `MyInt` with this kind of overridden `__new__` is almost equivalent to `class MyInt(int): pass`

Comment: @poke: That was implicit; made it explicit now.